Terminal stuck at every launch until Ctrl+C
Every time I successfully login to a remote server using ssh, the zsh terminal would stuck unless I do a Ctrl+C. There's no problem with the ssh login. It also requires three Ctrl+C after I type exit for it to really exit the ssh connection every time.
To see if anything's wrong with ~/.zshenv or ~/.zshrc, I commented out all of their content and added echo "End of ~/.zshenv" at the end of ~/.zshenv, and echo "End of ~/.zshrc" at the end of ~/.zshrc, the output of is as following:
Last login: Thu Aug  1 00:13:12 2024 from XX.XX.XXX.XXX
+/u/username/.zshenv:159> echo 'End of ~/.zshenv'
End of ~/.zshenv
+/etc/zprofile:6> [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ']'
+/etc/zprofile:7> /usr/libexec/path_helper -s
+/etc/zprofile:7> eval 'PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin";' export 'PATH;'
+(eval):1> PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
+(eval):1> export PATH
+/etc/zshrc:7> [[+/etc/zshrc:7> locale LC_CTYPE
+/etc/zshrc:7> [[ US-ASCII == UTF-8 ]]
+/etc/zshrc:12> disable log
+/etc/zshrc:15> HISTFILE=/u/username/.zsh_history
+/etc/zshrc:16> HISTSIZE=2000
+/etc/zshrc:17> SAVEHIST=1000
+/etc/zshrc:20> setopt BEEP
+/etc/zshrc:24> [[ -r /u/username/.zkbd/xterm-256color-apple ]]
+/etc/zshrc:27> typeset -g -A key
+/etc/zshrc:29> [[ -n $'\C-[OP' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:29> key[F1]=$'\C-[OP'
+/etc/zshrc:30> [[ -n $'\C-[OQ' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:30> key[F2]=$'\C-[OQ'
+/etc/zshrc:31> [[ -n $'\C-[OR' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:31> key[F3]=$'\C-[OR'
+/etc/zshrc:32> [[ -n $'\C-[OS' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:32> key[F4]=$'\C-[OS'
+/etc/zshrc:33> [[ -n $'\C-[[15~' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:33> key[F5]=$'\C-[[15~'
+/etc/zshrc:34> [[ -n $'\C-[[17~' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:34> key[F6]=$'\C-[[17~'
+/etc/zshrc:35> [[ -n $'\C-[[18~' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:35> key[F7]=$'\C-[[18~'
+/etc/zshrc:36> [[ -n $'\C-[[19~' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:36> key[F8]=$'\C-[[19~'
+/etc/zshrc:37> [[ -n $'\C-[[20~' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:37> key[F9]=$'\C-[[20~'
+/etc/zshrc:38> [[ -n $'\C-[[21~' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:38> key[F10]=$'\C-[[21~'
+/etc/zshrc:39> [[ -n $'\C-[[23~' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:39> key[F11]=$'\C-[[23~'
+/etc/zshrc:40> [[ -n $'\C-[[24~' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:40> key[F12]=$'\C-[[24~'
+/etc/zshrc:41> [[ -n $'\C-[[1;2P' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:41> key[F13]=$'\C-[[1;2P'
+/etc/zshrc:42> [[ -n $'\C-[[1;2Q' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:42> key[F14]=$'\C-[[1;2Q'
+/etc/zshrc:43> [[ -n $'\C-[[1;2R' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:43> key[F15]=$'\C-[[1;2R'
+/etc/zshrc:44> [[ -n $'\C-[[1;2S' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:44> key[F16]=$'\C-[[1;2S'
+/etc/zshrc:45> [[ -n $'\C-[[15;2~' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:45> key[F17]=$'\C-[[15;2~'
+/etc/zshrc:46> [[ -n $'\C-[[17;2~' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:46> key[F18]=$'\C-[[17;2~'
+/etc/zshrc:47> [[ -n $'\C-[[18;2~' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:47> key[F19]=$'\C-[[18;2~'
+/etc/zshrc:48> [[ -n $'\C-[[19;2~' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:48> key[F20]=$'\C-[[19;2~'
+/etc/zshrc:49> [[ -n $'\C-H' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:49> key[Backspace]=$'\C-H'
+/etc/zshrc:50> [[ -n $'\C-[[2~' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:50> key[Insert]=$'\C-[[2~'
+/etc/zshrc:51> [[ -n $'\C-[[3~' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:51> key[Delete]=$'\C-[[3~'
+/etc/zshrc:52> [[ -n $'\C-[OH' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:52> key[Home]=$'\C-[OH'
+/etc/zshrc:53> [[ -n $'\C-[OF' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:53> key[End]=$'\C-[OF'
+/etc/zshrc:54> [[ -n $'\C-[[5~' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:54> key[PageUp]=$'\C-[[5~'
+/etc/zshrc:55> [[ -n $'\C-[[6~' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:55> key[PageDown]=$'\C-[[6~'
+/etc/zshrc:56> [[ -n $'\C-[OA' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:56> key[Up]=$'\C-[OA'
+/etc/zshrc:57> [[ -n $'\C-[OD' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:57> key[Left]=$'\C-[OD'
+/etc/zshrc:58> [[ -n $'\C-[OB' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:58> key[Down]=$'\C-[OB'
+/etc/zshrc:59> [[ -n $'\C-[OC' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:59> key[Right]=$'\C-[OC'
+/etc/zshrc:63> [[ -n $'\C-[[3~' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:63> bindkey $'\C-[[3~' delete-char
+/etc/zshrc:64> [[ -n $'\C-[OH' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:64> bindkey $'\C-[OH' beginning-of-line
+/etc/zshrc:65> [[ -n $'\C-[OF' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:65> bindkey $'\C-[OF' end-of-line
+/etc/zshrc:66> [[ -n $'\C-[OA' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:66> bindkey $'\C-[OA' up-line-or-search
+/etc/zshrc:67> [[ -n $'\C-[OB' ]]
+/etc/zshrc:67> bindkey $'\C-[OB' down-line-or-search
+/etc/zshrc:70> PS1='%n@%m %1~ %# '
+/etc/zshrc:73> [ -r /etc/zshrc_ ']'
+/u/username/.zshrc:41> echo 'End of ~/.zshrc'
End of ~/.zshrc

And then it's stuck until a Ctrl+C is sent.
It does seem that ~/.zshenv and ~/.zshrc are finished executing but still somehow get stuck after that. So the solution to this question does not apply.
I also found out that ZDOTDIR and USER_ZDOTDIR are both empty variables after Ctrl+C, even though the ~/.zshenv and ~/.zshrc are executed. Tried in vscode, and the problem persists. But ZDOTDIR, USER_ZDOTDIR, and VSCODE_ZDOTDIR are home directory in vscode. I'm in desperate need of any suggestions that might help solving this issue! Appreciate it!

First thing I'd try is to rename those files, and start from scratch.

The problem is on the remote side.

You don’t mention .zlogin and .zlogout (or their /etc friends). Have you checked them?

(But, as Marc Wilson says in anther comment, the problem is on the remote system, so unless that, too, is a Mac, this isn’t really a Mac issue at all.)

Thanks for all your suggestions! I followed @benwiggy's advice and started new zshrc and zshenv files from scratch and it solves the problem somehow!

I managed to solve the problem by renaming ~/.zshrc and ~/.zshenv files to something else and created empty ~/.zshrc and ~/.zshenv from scratch as @benwiggy suggested in the comment. Then I carefully move the lines from the old files to the new ones chunk by chunk accompanied with constant testing to ensure there's not any special characters.
Also, @Ture Pålsson's comment is also very helpful in terms of which files are loaded at login and could go wrong. Be sure to check them out!
